# need to use return type string array method

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

i have a method

```
public string[] getlist()
    {
      -----
      -----
      Return Result.toString();
    }
```

How do i call this method in my main method and show all the list using 
`console.write(result)` in loop

Thanks

Comment: C# is case-sensitive.  `Return` won't compile.  Change it to `return` in your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `Join()` will do the work just fine no need in loop:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", myObj.getList()));
```

Comment: The OP might not be aware there is better alternative. His final goal looks like just showing the values.

Answer (score 1):

use a `foreach (var result in retrivedString) {Console.Write(result);}`

Answer (score 1):

Obviously that method is incorrect as it's trying to return a string instead of an array.

However assuming myObject is an instance of what ever Object type has this method.

```
foreach(string str in myObject.getlist())
{
  Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```